# Retrieving data from my e-mail on outlook with R

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient

I've been trying to retrieve some of my e-mails in order to have them as data in R. In case it is needed, it is on a Microsoft Exchange Server.

```
require(RDCOMClient)
folderName = 'ElastAlerts'

#creating the outlook object

OutApp <- COMCreate('Outlook.Application')
outlookNameSpace <- OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

folder <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders(folderName)
```

But the final line shows me the following error:

```
<checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and resolved it after playing around it.

Possible solutions,

In
`folder <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders(folderName)`

This instead of using "1" try using "2" or "3", it works for me.

Don't know why it is changing folder index.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the specified folder exists in the store.

> But the final line shows me the following error:
>
> ```
>  folder <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders(folderName)
> ```

The specified line of code contains multiple property and method calls. I'd recommend breaking the chain of method calls and declaring a single method call on a separate line of code. That way you will be able to find a method or property which fails.

Note, you can iterate over all folder in the folder and find the required one by using the `Name` property.

Comment: Hello. I did what you suggested. I made it this way: `folder <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)` and it didn't show an error message. I also tried using `folderName <- 'Inbox'` but it is not working. Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: how did you fix this specifically?

Comment: Use the Ganesh answer. You gotta check thoroughly the Folders. I happen to loose the code that I used for it.